# Sinch Production Keys Not Working

Tags: android, sinch

Hey so I have been working on an app which includes Sinch Messaging in it. Everything was working fine with the Sandbox key and secret. I am planning on putting the app in the Play Store and decided it was time to enter in the Sinch production keys. However, as soon as I do this, the Sinch client suddenly stops working. I did the following test to check if the client was starting

```
Log.e("ClientStarted", String.valueOf(messageService.isSinchClientStarted()));
```

It returns true when I am using the sandbox keys but when I input the production keys, it returns false. Somehow the client is not starting with the production keys. Anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed environment url to live?

Comment: So I got an email from SInch this morning saying they had updated the environment to live. I guess maybe there is an approvals process for this. Pardon my impatience